# What does Nov 2h or 2h NOV mean?

Tags: date, date-format

I saw a file with date strings like "Nov 2h" or "2h Nov". My native language is not English, so I don't know what that means. Can somebody tell me what's the meaning of it? Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a programming question; ask the person that created the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a format I'm familiar with and I'm a native english speaker.  I can only guess it means the 2nd of November, though usually a number followed by an 'h' usually means hour.  Without more information, I'm afraid I can't help you much.

Comment: got it.many thanks. it maybe a typo